# Convert (ASCII) char string to floating point - C/C++ & Matlab

Tags: c++, c, matlab, floating-point, ascii

I need some help converting ASCII characters string to a single floating point number. 
My data has the following format:

> ìÀV3é¾V3»V3AÀV3ÁV3Û¶V3ÅV3=¾V3âºV3ðÂV3ß¸V3¿V3é¾V3ÁV3Û¶V3é¾V3ìÀV3ÁV3é¾V3ÁV3=¾V3DÂV3DÂV30¶V¿V3:¼V3¿V3ìÀV3,´V3¿V3·V3ìÀV3

Each four characters should represent a floating point number. e.g.: 50.90101e-9;

I am trying to covert this string into readable data using the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int no_of_bytes;
    char temp_string[2048];
    float this_reading[100];
    char *ptr;
    no_of_bytes=32;

    sprintf(temp_string,"%i",no_of_bytes*4);

    /*convert char string to floating point*/
    sprintf(temp_string,"%i","ìÀV3é¾V3»V3AÀV3ÁV3Û¶V3ÅV3=¾V3âºV3ðÂV3ß¸V3¿V3é¾V3ÁV3Û¶V3é¾V3ìÀV3ÁV3é¾V3ÁV3=¾V3DÂV3DÂV30¶V¿V3:¼V3¿V3ìÀV3,´V3¿V3·V3ìÀV3");
    ptr=&temp_string [1];
    /*convert char string to floating point*/
    for(i=0; i<no_of_bytes; i++)
    {
        //puts(ptr);
        this_reading [i] = *((float*)ptr);
        ptr = ptr+4;
        printf ("%e \n", this_reading [i]);
    }
}
/*end of main*/
```

But I get the following results:

```
6.665629e-10 
-6.321715e-30 
4.056162e-02 
-5.629500e+14 
1.259217e-18 
1.779649e-43 
3.087247e+23 
2.350968e-38 
-2.437012e+01 
9.439035e-38 
0.000000e+00 
-2.000000e+00 
-nan 
1.661560e+35 
4.056162e-02 
-5.629500e+14 
1.259217e-18 
1.779649e-43 
3.096102e+23 
2.350968e-38 
-2.437012e+01 
1.628646e+32 
0.000000e+00 
6.490371e+32 
0.000000e+00 
0.000000e+00 
2.596148e+33 
0.000000e+00 
1.038459e+34 
4.153837e+34 
0.000000e+00 
0.000000e+00
```

I tried to take a float number, closed to the value which I a looking to convert, to convert it to character and back to float using the same method and I also get the same errors in results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{

    float reading;
    float number;
    char *ptr;
    float *pointer_number;
    char temp_char ;

    number = 50.90101e-9;
   pointer_number = & number;

    printf ("%e \n",*pointer_number);
    temp_char  = *((char*)pointer_number);

    printf ("%c \n",temp_char);

   ptr=&temp_char ;
    puts(ptr);

    reading  = *((float*)ptr);
    printf ("%f \n", reading);

}
/*end of main*/
```

.

```
5.090101e-08 
A 
AA�Z3
22272396874481664.000000
```

I am not an expert in C/C++ data declaration an manipulation. My final purpose is to make this conversion in Matlab.
I am reading this value from a very old instrument. They are specifying in the instrument manual that the queries data support two sizes of data types using IEEE standards for floating-point arithmetic (ANSI/IEEE Std. 754-1985).

Thank you!

Comment: Most of that first string doesn't look like ASCII characters.

Comment: You tagged your question C, but said C++ in the question body, but your code looks like C except for the `#include <iostream>` which is C++. Make up your mind which language you're using...

Comment: You may think your data looks like that, but I think somewhere along the line, your data was a byte array that was mistakenly displayed as a string.  There are byte values that don't print as an ASCII character, so this conversion can destroy data.  If you *must have* ASCII, use a hex conversion or something.

Comment: The code is displayed as C/C++ in that instrument manual.

The data look like this actually. I am 'spying' my GPIB communication channel and this is what I receive. I also have a very old windows software (from the instrument) that can do the same reading. The software reads the same data and can display the values.

Comment: The characters you post do not look like typical floating-point data in the common IEEE 754 format, either float or double, little-endian or big-endian, starting at the initial byte or the next one, in the sense that all interpretations yield values that are quite large or quite small. (E.g., the closest magnitude to one I found was -2.22482e-06.) If the characters have been altered in the course of copying them to Stack Overflow, be sure they are not altered in your actual program. If you are not able to read the actual binary data without change, you have a bigger problem than converting.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil  I had similar trouble too.  For me, Cygwin Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 converting the so called ASCII string into a UTF8 encoding which made overlaying floats problematic.  I put the string in a file with an "ASCII" (sic) encoding which I then read in binary with better success.  Still think the string OP presented does not match the real binary data the OP has _somewhere_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 10 values are

```
0 5.000122e-08
1 4.999939e-08
2 ?
3 5.000061e-08
4 ?
5 4.999206e-08
6 4.985647e-08
7 4.999878e-08
8 4.999573e-08
9 5.000305e-08
...
```

Your example of `50.90101e-9` converted to `A � Z 3` on my 4-byte little endian float `C` computer.  As the `Z 3` is similar to ever 3rd,4th char (almost) it hinted that your *string* has the same little endian float format.  There are 2 problems with putting your string in a C file.  In my C file it, it converted the "ìÀV3é¾ ..." string to UTF8 encoding.  By unionizing that with floats led to confusion.  Your string, as presented, is certainly missing some bytes.  (I added a few to get past float #2.)  I assume the true string is available in its original form in a file.  Open the file in binary and read that file 4 bytes at a time as `float`.

```
FILE *inf = fopen("Stringfilename", "rb");
int i = 0;
float f;
while (fread(&f, sizeof(f), 1, inf) == 1) {
  printf("%d %e\n", i++, f);
}
fclose(inf);
printf("%d floats read.\n", i);
```

Comment: I get these readings using Matlab and accessing visa32.dll to read from an instrument via GPIB connection. My readings are numerical. > 'ret = 35 51 49 50 56 82 202 86 51 51 184 86 51 > 58 188 86 51 156 195 86 51 145 189 86 51 71 196 > 86 51 .... For all other instrument a simple 'char(ret)' %Matlab would be enough to convert the reading to the actual data. Though, the reading from is instrument is converted to the string which I posted above.

Comment: Using a simple GPIB Spy program, I could get the actual ASCII reading: > ret = R.V33.V3:.V3..V3..V3G.V3A.V3..V3..V3A.V3..V36.V3A.V36.V3..V3:.V3..V3..V3..V3..V3‌​..V3..V36.V3..V3D.V3A.V3..V33.V3..V3=.V3..V33.V3. Using the code which you provided, I get the following results: 0 4.986789e-08 1 4.986778e-08 2 4.986780e-08 3 4.986776e-08 4 4.986776e-08 This results makes sense and it is the actual data which I am searching for. Thank you very much for your help Though, in Matlab I cannot use 'printf('%e\n',ret(i))', because it converts the ASCII characters one by one.

Comment: One more question, please. 
I have in this case, 4 bytes conversion to long - 6 digit precision.
I can read my data on 15 digits precision, but I need to covert 8 bytes into double. 
What is the specifier in 'printf' for 8 bytes reading?
Thank you!

Comment: To print `double`, add an `l` to "%e", "%f" or "%g".  Example: `printf("%lf", ...);`.

Comment: BTW: Avoid calling the bytes you read "ASCII".  "ASCII" is defined for byte values 0 - 127, but not for bytes values 128-255.  Your `ìÀV3é¾...` is _not_ an ASCII string.  It is not ASCII because it has characters outside the ASCII range like `À`.  It is not a typical string because your stream of bytes _could_ have embedded NUL bytes and likely does not have a terminating NUL byte either.  Calling it a byte array is better.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `temp_string` contains garbage.

```
sprintf(temp_string,"%i", string_literal)
```

is wrong.  `%i` is not compatible with a character pointer, but because `sprintf` is a varargs function, the compiler never knows you have a type mismatch.

Lose the `sprintf`, try just

```
const char* ptr = "...";
```

and then your loop should work.

Or even simpler:

```
const float *this_reading = (float*)"...";
```

and then just use it like you would an array.

Of course, all this code makes assumptions about the byte-order of your data matching the C++ platform.  But if you're more interested in number crunching it should "work well enough".